# Input box to redirect to specific ports on same URL not working

Tags: javascript, html

I wish this to redirect an inputted port to redirect to same url with port,

Someone helped me this far but still have no luck...

```
<script>
document.getElementById('myForm').addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault(); 

    // Get the value from the input field
    const port = document.getElementById('portNumber').value;
    const baseUrl = "h--ps://mysite.com";
    window.location.href = '${baseUrl}:${port}';
    
});
</script>



<form id="myForm" method="post" action="javascript:void(0)">
    <input type="number" name="" id="myForm" placeholder="Port Number.." />
    <input type="submit" value="Go"/>
</form>
```

Ok this works now with corrections supplied by erman999...

But found out script must be placed AFTER the Body

Comment: What happens when you run this? Are there any errors in the console?

Comment: What's this supposed to get `document.getElementById('portNumber')`? And note that you're using `id="myForm"` twice. IDs **must** be unique

Comment: "Not working" is generally a bad way to describe a problem. Instead, describe what you expect to happen, *and what happens instead*. In this case, I'm guessing the browser attempts to navigate to the literal `${baseUrl}:${port}` which is obviously not a valid URL. Using the appropriate quote character would help here (`\``), as would using a real `baseUrl` scheme. Adjusting the ids in the HTML to match those used in the JavaScript would round out the fixes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not very far from target but you have some small mistakes.

- `myForm` should not be used more than one element.
- Template literals work with backtick not with single quote.
- id of your input must be `portNumber`

---

Before trying below example make sure that given address will throw an error because of `"h--ps://mysite.com"`.

```js
document.getElementById('myForm').addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  // Get the value from the input field
  const port = document.getElementById('portNumber').value;
  const baseUrl = "h--ps://mysite.com";
  console.log(`${baseUrl}:${port}`);
  window.location.href = `${baseUrl}:${port}`;
});
```

```html
  <form id="myForm" method="post" action="javascript:void(0)">
    <input type="number" id="portNumber" name="" placeholder="Port Number.." />
    <input type="submit" value="Go"/>
  </form>
```

Comment: Thanks, I add the actual URL in place of mysite.com and nothing happens, Starting to think maybe javascript isn't installed on my server

Comment: It runs well on an online js tester just not my server

Comment: You didn't mentioned about server port forwarding. It's a completely different subject. Your question and provided codes for browser forwarding. If you need help on server side javascript, share your `node.js` codes.

Comment: Just needed the script after the body not before.. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

```
window.location.href = `${baseUrl}:${port}`;
```

use ` instead of '

```
<input type="number" name="" id="portNumber" placeholder="Port Number.." />
```

You forgot to change id="portNumber" in input.

Answer (score 0):

Use the name attribute for both form and input element. Use a [template literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) (the back tics) for creating the URL.

```js
document.forms.form01.addEventListener('submit', e => {
  e.preventDefault();
  const baseUrl = "h--ps://mysite.com";
  window.location.href = `${baseUrl}:${e.target.portnumber.value}`;
});
```

```html
<form name="form01" method="post">
  <input type="number" name="portnumber" placeholder="Port Number.." />
  <input type="submit" value="Go" />
</form>
```